# How I can retrieve the Image Url of a given product?

Tags: magento2.4, product-images

I have a custom block in magento 2.4 where I retrieve a image List

```
namespace Pcmagas\FirstModule\Block\MyList;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class MyList extends Template
{
    private ProductRepository $productRepository;

    private SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder;

    public function __construct(
        Template\Context $context,
        ProductRepository $productRepository,
        SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
    }

    public function getRelatedProducts()
    {
        $skuList = ['24-MB01','24-MB04','24-UG01'];
        $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter('sku', $skuList, 'in')->create();

        return $this->productRepository->getList($searchCriteria)->getItems();
    }
}
```

And upon my phtml file I list the products like this:

```
    <?php foreach ($products as $product): ?>
        <div>
            <-- Display Image Here -->
            <h4>
                <?=$product->getName(); ?>
            </h4>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

But if I try to do:

```
<?=$product->getImage(); ?>
```

I will get the path towards the image and NOT the actual Image. Is there  a way to get the Image URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most common approach is to retrieve the image html instead. The reason hwy is because images can also be loaded from CDN as well:

```
namespace Pcmagas\FirstModule\Block\MyList;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;


// Also ad this
use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ImageBuilder;


class MyList extends Template
{

   public function __construct(
        Template\Context $context,
        ProductRepository $productRepository,
        SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
        ImageBuilder $builder,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
    
    }

    // Implement this one
     public function getImageHtml(Product $product)
    {
        return $this->builder->create($product,'category_page_list')->toHtml();
    }
}
```

And Upon phtml use:

```
 <?php foreach ($products as $product): ?>
        <div>
            <!-- consume getImageHtml to retrieve ther actual image -->
            <?=$block->getImageHtml($product);?>
            <h4>
                <?=$product->getName(); ?>
            </h4>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```